# IE throwing error for FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is a new thing. At least up to IE 8 getting a doesn't support method in all.js and seems to be breaking on the FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

This is stopping our auto resize from working in IE and I can't seem to get a workaround that works without throwing some kind of exception.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId  : js_fb_app_id,
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
    oauth   : true          
  });

  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **window.fbAsyncInit** hook to execute **FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();**

**window.fbAsyncInit** function will be executed when the Facebook library is loaded, but not when the whole page is loaded.

When the page in not fully loaded the **FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();** will not work correctly because will not know the correct height of your content. You can use window.onload to execute **FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();** when the page if fully loaded.

Try this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : js_fb_app_id,
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth   : true          
    });
};
window.onload=function(){
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. Every thing I try for deferred loading of scripts barfs same line in all.js (line 15) from fb.

Comment: Can you post the error from js ? My thought was that if the page is not fully loaded some methods will not work as expected and therefore result such errors.

Comment: it's the vague IE js error Object doesn't support this property or method (line 15) all.js

Comment: thanks, I brute forced it in a jquery $(document).ready and it seems to fire now.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to load your javascript file as asynchronous this means that it will execute only after finishing loading the whole file, this might be your case the import statement should look like next:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: yes my async is setup and just stopped working for no real reason, I have voted for some bugs, just hoping someone has run into this IE specific thing and made some sort of workaround.